# MATLAB Automate GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, automation

I currently have a GUI that outputs a single text file based on various input parameters. However, I need to modify my application such that the GUI outputs multiple text files based on N inputs. The original GUI designer is no longer available and the main m-file has over 5k lines of code making it difficult to troubleshoot (not to mention the code is very unorganized and not commented). Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can run the GUI N times based on the N inputs and output N text files without modifying the original m-file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your gui is called myApp and your callback to s called myButton_Callback.
I also assumng that the tag of the uicontrol is 'myButton'.

Here is the caller script:

```
myApp_h = myApp();
myApp_handles = guidata(myApp_h);
myButton_h = myApp_handles.myButton;
MyApp('myButton_Callback', myButton_h, myApp_handles);
```

You can automate any gui control by this method.